# Print multiple rows from database into table

Tags: php, mysql

Could anyone tell me how to adapt or change this code to print multiple rows from a database table into an html table using PHP? Every user will have a different number of records in the table so I will need to use some kind of loop to print out the rows.

```
<?php

                    include_once 'dbconfig.php';

                    $statement = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM entry WHERE user_id=:uid");
                    $statement->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['user_session']));
                    $result=$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    ?>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Entry</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Weight</th>
                            <th>BMI</th>
                            <th>Calories Consumed</th>
                            <th>Calories Burned</th>
                            <th>Calorific Deficit</th>
                        </tr>

                    <?php

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

        $entry = $row["entry_id"];           
        $date = $row["date"]; 
        $weight = $row["weight"];
        $bmi = $row["bmi"]; 
        $consumed = $row["calories_consumed"]; 
        $burned = $row["calories_burned"];
        $deficit = $row["calorie_deficit"]; 

        echo "<tr>
        <td>$entry</td>
        <td>$date</td>
        <td>$weight</td>
        <td>$bmi</td>
        <td>$consumed</td>
        <td>$burned</td>
        <td>$deficit</td>
        </tr>";

}

                    ?>

                        </table>
```

This currently works fine but it only prints out the first row relevant to the particular user rather than looping through and printing a row for each record.

*Updated to include while loop*

Comment: `while(something is true) { do this }`

Comment: I have updated my answer with what I have now but for some reason it isn't printing any rows after the header row

Comment: You're mixing PDO with `mysql_`, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row =$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $title1 = $row["title1"]; 
            $title2 = $row["titl2"]; 
            $title3 = $row["title3"]; 

            echo "<tr> 
            <td>$title1</td>
            <td>$title2</td>
            <td>$title3</td>
             </tr>";
    }
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this earlier and now tried it this way.  For some reason it isn't returning any data into the table.

Comment: I've tried this code and it does seem to be an improvement as the relevant rows have been added when I check using the inspector tools.  However the data still isn't being added to each cell

Comment: Fixed! I changed the for the while loop to 
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) and this solved my problem.  Thanks for your help Draviya!